# How to get variable data from prepend/append and do addition with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to create an invoicing system. I have a form that I add fields to for every line item and that works I can add and remove the form fields. My problem is I dont know a way to get the price from the prepended line item and add it up to get a subtotal.

this is the html nothing interesting here

```
<div class="form-row">
    <strong>Line Items:</strong>
    <br>
        <div class="line-items">
            <div class="line-item">
                <div class="line-item-box description">
                    <label>Description:</label>
                    <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="line-item-box quantity">
                <label>Qty:</label>
                <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity">
            </div>
            <div class="line-item-box price">
                <label>Price:</label>
                <input type="text" name="price" id="price">
            </div>
            <button class="btn add-item">Add Item</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-item').click(function() {
        var description = $('#description').val();
        var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
        var price = $('#price').val();
        $('.line-items').prepend('<div class="line-item"><div class="line-item-box description">' + description + '</div><div class="line-item-box quantity">' + quantity + '</div><div class="line-item-box price price-saved">$' + price*quantity + '</div><button class="btn remove-btn">Remove</button></div>');
        if (!$('.price-summation')[0]) {
            $('.line-items').append('<div class="price-summation"><div class="price-row">' + subtotal + '</div><div class="price-row">Taxes</div><div class="price-row">Total</div></div>');
        }
        return false;
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.remove-btn', function() {
        $('.line-item').remove();
    });
});
```

So I would like to add up the price var for each line item which will be added to the dom dynamically and then display it with the subtotal var.

Is this possible? If so how can I do this?

Comment: I know this difference between and #id and a .class. That has nothing to do with my question as far as I can tell. Perhaps I was unclear. Would you like me to rephrase my question?

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question you did find an error I was making creating multiple ids. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a total use a each loop and sum each parsed value of the price,put this in a function and trigger it each time you update the list of items

js:

```
   function price_subtotal(){
       var subtotal = 0;
        $('.price-saved').each(function(i,v){
          subtotal+= parseFloat($(v).text().replace('$',''));
        });

        $('.subtotal').html(subtotal);
    }
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-item').click(function() {
        var description = $('#description').val();
        var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
        var price = $('#price').val();
        $('.line-items').prepend('<div class="line-item"><div class="line-item-box description">' + description + '</div><div class="line-item-box quantity">' + quantity + '</div><div class="line-item-box price price-saved">$' + price*quantity + '</div><button class="btn remove-btn">Remove</button></div>');


        if (!$('.price-summation')[0]) {
            $('.line-items').append('<div class="price-summation"><div class="subtotal price-row">0</div><div class="price-row">Taxes</div><div class="price-row">Total</div></div>');
        }
        price_subtotal();
        return false;
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.remove-btn', function() {
        $(this).closest('.line-item').remove();
        price_subtotal();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ttgr44by/)

Comment: it is better to add a few lines of explanation why you answer this and why OP's code didnt work.

Comment: I tried the code above but when I add a line item all the output variables are undefined and NaN

Comment: sory about that you had $ in with your price

Comment: I have tried with the adjusted code but still getting undefined variables. Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4bvocthm/1/

Comment: still getting undefined variables. See the updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4bvocthm/2/